# My app is giving exception when I'm using textchangelistener and onclicklistener on same edittext

Tags: android

I am developing an app. In this app I am using multiple edittext in an activity but getting exceptions. I am using textchangelistener and onclick listener on every edit text. onclick to clear that edittext and textchangelistener to set a value on textview but it is not working.

Comment: post your code  here

Comment: must paste code and log

Comment: Please share your exception log

Comment: unable to add the code

Comment: actually i am new here so don't know how to do